# Better way in TSQL to search xml for a node that doesn't exist

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery

We have a source `XML` file that has an `address` node, and each node is supposed to have a `zip_code` node beneath in order to validate.  We received a file that failed the schema validation because at least one node was missing it's zip_code (there were several thousand addresses in the file).

We need to find the elements that do not have a zip code, so we can repair the file and send an audit report to the source.

```
--declare @x xml = bulkcolumn from openrowset(bulk 'x:\file.xml',single_blob) as s
declare @x xml = N'<addresses>
    <address><external_address_id>1</external_address_id><zip_code>53207</zip_code></address>
    <address><external_address_id>2</external_address_id></address>
</addresses>'

declare @t xml = (
select @x.query('for $a in .//address 
    return 
        if ($a/zip_code) 
            then <external_address_id /> 
        else $a/external_address_id')
)
select x.AddressID.value('.', 'int') AddressID
from @t.nodes('./external_address_id') x(AddressID)
where x.AddressID.value('.', 'int') > 0
GO
```

Really, it's the `where` clause that bugs me.  I feel like I'm depending on a cast for a `null` value to `0`, and it works, but I'm not really sure that it should.  I tried a few variations with the `.exist` function, but I couldn't get the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to locate those nodes that are missing their `<zip_code>` element, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT
    ADRS.ADR.value('(external_address_id)[1]', 'int') as 'ExtAdrID'
FROM
    @x.nodes('/addresses/address') as ADRS(ADR)
WHERE
    ADRS.ADR.exist('zip_code') = 0
```

It uses the built-in `.exist()` method in XQuery to check the existence of a subnode inside an XML node.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to ensure that you are selecting `address` elements that have a `zip_code` element, then adjust your XPATH to include that criteria in a predicate filter:

```
/addresses/address[zip_code]
```

If you also want to ensure that the `zip_code` element also has a value, use a predicate filter for the `zip_node` to select those that have `text()` nodes:

```
/addresses/address[zip_code[text()]]
```

---

**EDIT:**

> Actually, I'm looking for the
>   opposite. I need to identify the nodes
>   that don't have a zip, so we can
>   manually correct the source data.

So, if you want to identify all of the `address` elements that *do not* have a `zip_code`, you can specify it in the XPATH like this:

```
/addresses/address[not(zip_code)]
```

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for the opposite.  I need to identify the nodes that don't have a zip, so we can manually correct the source data.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  I've updated with an example of how you can address just the `address` elements that do not have a `zip_code`.